# Get data from external API with a asp.net core API

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api

I'm learning to create APIs using ASP.NET core, in this I came up with a problem, I'm trying to execute a request for an external API using my API, but I do not know how to execute the request and return the JSON of the request, any help?

The flow of the application looks something like this:

**SPA -> AspNet Core WEB API -> External API**

What I've done so far:

```
[Route("api/[Controller]")]
    public class RankingsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IRankingRepository _rankingRepository;

        public RankingsController(IRankingRepository rankingRepo)
        {
            _rankingRepository = rankingRepo;
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetRanking")]
        public IActionResult GetById(long id)
        //Here is where I want to make the requisition
        }

    }
```

I need to make the request for this API:

http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/{id}/leagueTable

*In the ID location, I need to pass a parameter that comes from the request made in my API;*

Any help for this problem?

Sorry for not being such a complex question.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use an `HttpClient` instance to achieve what you want. However, I always find easier to use [RestSharp](https://restsharp.dev/) though.

That, of course will depend on your constraints but assuming you have none for this case, you could use **RestSharp** to make the call to the external API:

**Install it:**

`Install-Package RestSharp`

**Usage:**

```
using RestSharp;

[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetRanking")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByIdAync(long id)
{
    var client = new RestClient($"http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/{id}/leagueTable");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

    //TODO: transform the response here to suit your needs
   
    return Ok(data);
}
```

To consume the rest response from RestSharp you must use the `response.Content` property.

You could, for example, deserialize it to Json, manipulate it to fit your needs and return the required data to your API caller.

**Example:**

Let's say I'd like to get the rankings for the Premier League 2017/18 (Id = 445):

*I'll get a lot of help below from the legendary [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) package and a little of `jpath` syntax but I'll assume you've already used both* :)

**Create a couple models to hold the values to be returned to the API caller:**

```
public class LeagueTableModel
{
    public string LeagueCaption { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<StandingModel> Standings { get; set; }
}
public class StandingModel
{
    public string TeamName { get; set; }

    public int Position { get; set; }
}
```

Implement the below method in the service class, injected to your controller through DI/IoC to avoid coupling and increase testability (as we all know we should do right?). I'm assuming this class is `RankingRepository` in your sample:

```
public RankingRepository: IRankingRepository 
{
    public Task<LeagueTableModel> GetRankingsAsync(long id)
    {
        var client = new RestClient($"http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/{id}/leagueTable");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
        if (response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(response.Content);
    
            //Get the league caption
            var leagueCaption = content["leagueCaption"].Value<string>();
    
            //Get the standings for the league.
            var rankings = content.SelectTokens("standing[*]")
                .Select(team => new StandingModel
                {
                    TeamName = (string)team["teamName"],
                    Position = (int)team["position"]
                })
                .ToList();
    
            //return the model to my caller.
            return new LeagueTableModel
            {
                LeagueCaption = leagueCaption,
                Standings = rankings
            };
        }
    
        //TODO: log error, throw exception or do other stuffs for failed requests here.
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Use it from the controller:**

```
[Route("api/[Controller]")]
public class RankingsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRankingRepository _rankingRepository;

    public RankingsController(IRankingRepository rankingRepo)
    {
        _rankingRepository = rankingRepo;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetRanking")]
    public Task<IActionResult> GetByIdAsync(long id)
        //Here is where I want to make the requisition
        var model = await _rankingRepository.GetRankingsAsync(id);
        
        //Validate if null
        if (model == null)
            return NotFound(); //or any other error code accordingly. Bad request is a strong candidate also.

        return Ok(model);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I suggest to use async programming model based on async and await keywords to improve responsiveness. Something like this: `public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(long id) { IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);`

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge, it worked perfectly!